# How can I remove the portion of a string that comes before ; if there is more than one semicolon in the string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If given the string "John Doe;Lodging;123;050617", which is a line within a file, I need to remove everything before and including the first semicolon, and after and including the last one. How can I do that without removing my ability to later split the remaining substring?

Previous questions do not address removing the portions once separated while retaining the portion needed for further use.

Comment: What do you want the string to look like? That would help make this question more clear. What final results do you want?

Comment: The same answers apply there. Just split and then join what you want.

Comment: I need Lodging;123 (Which will change because these are inputs from a .txt file). I then need to split the remaining substring and add each half to a list of categories and values, respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stepwise for clarity:

```
string = "John Doe;Lodging;123;050617"
lst = string.split(';')
lst = lst[1:-1]
string = ';'.join(lst)
print(string)
>>> 'Lodging;123'
```

As one line:

```
';'.join('John Doe;Lodging;123;050617'.split(';')[1:-1])
>>> 'Lodging;123'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
test = "John Doe;Lodging;123;050617"
';'.join(test.split(';')[1:-1])
```

Comment: indexing twice is not necessary, you can just use `[1:-1]`

Answer (score 2):

```
s = "John Doe;Lodging;123;050617"
new_s = ';'.join(s.split(';')[1:-1])
```

This will make `new_s = 'Lodging;123'`

Answer (score 0):

The find method will give you the index of the first instance of a character in a string

```
original_s="John Doe;Lodging;123;050617"
idx = original_s.find(';')
new_s = original_s[i+1:]
print(new_s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) and [`str.rpartition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition).

```
s = "John Doe;Lodging;123;050617"
s.partition(';')[-1].rpartition(';')[0] # Lodging;123
```

In terms of efficiency, this is probably the best solution. However, I find the split/join method more readable.

Comment: This doesn't give the output OP wants, "John Doh;" and ";050617" need to be removed. BTW I didn't downvote this

Comment: @jacoblaw updated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a few methods you could try.  The simplest one is to split the string and reassemble it:

```
data = 'John Doe;Lodging;123;050617'
';'.join(data.split(';')[1:-1])
```

You could also use `find` and `rfind` (like find, but from the end of the string backwards:

```
data[data.find(';')+1:data.rfind(';')]
```

There's also `partition` and `rpartition`:

```
first, sep, remainder = data.partition(';')
middle, sep, final = remainder.rpartition(';')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
s = "John Doe;Lodging;123;050617"
print(';'.join(s.split(';')[1:-1]))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this: use `str.find()` function to locate the first occurance of `';'` and then substring from that point to the end using `[:]`

```
aStr = "John Doe;Lodging;123;050617"
aStr = aStr[aStr.find(';')+1:]
print(aStr)
Lodging;123;050617
```

Comment: This doesn't give the output OP wants, "John Doh;" and ";050617" need to be removed. BTW I didn't downvote this

Comment: Good point, I missed that part of the problem. The OP question was not clear imo.